# UITableview view reload animation issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uiviewanimation

Please see the video for animation issue in UITableview. When I get the data from the API and refresh cell than the first cell animation issue when it is expanded.

I used below code for reload cell.

```
self.tblSpDirectoryView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 3, section: 0)], with: .none)
```

I have also tried to belove solutions for that.

```
self.tblSpDirectoryView.beginUpdates()
                    self.tblSpDirectoryView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 3, section: 0)], with: .none)
                    self.tblSpDirectoryView.endUpdates()
```

Before all above code, I have used only the reload.

```
self.tblSpDirectoryView.reloadData()
```

It was not helpfull for me. I have share video file for understanding [please find video file here.](https://file.fm/u/yttrymzu)

Comment: remove `self.tblSpDirectoryView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 3, section: 0)], with: .none)` the between begin and endUpdates

Comment: Are you calculating cell height programatically ?

Comment: Yes, but I have tried set as 140 for expand and 500 for expanding. but same issue. do you have any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add:

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

Also you can try to calculate all your cells heights. 
And pass them to the method `tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)`

[See my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49288428/8069241)

Answer (score 0):

Your first code is correct for reload section you are using swift 3 kindly try this code
`let indexPath = IndexPath(item: row, section: 0)
tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)`

Animation is not happening correctly, if your table view is static kindly check height in both storyboard and tableview height delegate method, if you are using xib the check in that also.If the differs from the storyboard and in the code the it will reflect like this.